# Изменение аватарки на сайте

Tags: php

Когда пользователь регистрируется, он добавляет свою аватарку, она переименовывается в его логин + единичка. Пример логин: `Lordy`, аватарка переименовывается в `Lordy1`. Также у меня есть страничка изменения личных данных, в том числе и аватары (полный код внизу). Ниже я выписал часть кода, в котором определяется имя картинки. `$date` - это переменная, в которую записывается время. Мне необходимо вписать вместо `$date` что-то, возвращающее логин.

```
$date=time();
imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory.$date."1.jpg");//сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку,    именем будет текущее время. Сделано, чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых    имен.
//почему    именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается анимирование gif    изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень приятно читать его    комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то движение.
$avatar =    $path_to_90_directory. $date."1.jpg";//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.
```

### Вот весь код

```
else if    (isset($_FILES['fupload']['name'])) //отправлялась    ли переменная
                  {
if (empty($_FILES['fupload']['name']))
            {
            //если    переменная пустая (пользователь не отправил изображение),то присваиваем ему    заранее приготовленную картинку с надписью "нет аватара"
            $avatar =    "avatars/net-avatara.jpg"; //можете    нарисовать net-avatara.jpg или взять в исходниках
            $result7 = mysql_query("SELECT avatar    FROM users WHERE login='$old_login'",$db);//извлекаем текущий аватар 
            $myrow7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7);
            if ($myrow7['avatar'] == $ava)    {//если аватар был стандартный, то не удаляем    его, ведь у на одна картинка на всех.
            $ava = 1;
            }
            else {unlink    ($myrow7['avatar']);}//если аватар был свой, то    удаляем его, затем поставим стандарт
            }
else 
            {
            //иначе    - загружаем изображение пользователя для обновления
            $path_to_90_directory =    'avatars/';//папка, куда будет загружаться    начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия

            if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload']['name']))//проверка формата исходного изображения

                             {

                                           $filename    = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
                                           $source    = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];        
                                           $target    = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
                                           move_uploaded_file($source, $target);//загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory 
                if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/',    $filename)) {
                            $im    = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ; //если оригинал был в формате gif, то создаем    изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                            }
                            if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {

                            $im =    imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ;//если    оригинал был в формате png, то создаем изображение в этом же формате.    Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                            }

                            if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/',    $filename)) {
                                           $im =    imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory.$filename); //если оригинал был в формате jpg, то создаем изображение в этом же    формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                            }

            //СОЗДАНИЕ    КВАДРАТНОГО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ И ЕГО ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЖАТИЕ ВЗЯТО С САЙТА www.codenet.ru
//    Создание квадрата 90x90
            //    dest - результирующее изображение 
            //    w - ширина изображения 
            //    ratio - коэффициент пропорциональности 
$w = 90;  // квадратная    90x90. Можно поставить и другой размер.
//    создаём исходное изображение на основе 
            //    исходного файла и определяем его размеры 
            $w_src = imagesx($im); //вычисляем ширину
            $h_src = imagesy($im); //вычисляем высоту изображения
         //    создаём пустую квадратную картинку 
                     // важно именно truecolor!, иначе    будем иметь 8-битный результат 
                     $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$w); 
nbsp;        //    вырезаем квадратную серединку по x, если фото горизонтальное 
                     if ($w_src>$h_src) 
                        imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0,
                                         round((max($w_src,$h_src)-min($w_src,$h_src))/2),
                                     0, $w, $w,    min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src)); 
            // вырезаем квадратную верхушку по    y, 
                     // если фото вертикальное (хотя    можно тоже серединку) 
                     if ($w_src<$h_src) 
                        imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w,
                                      min($w_src,$h_src),    min($w_src,$h_src)); 
         //    квадратная картинка масштабируется без вырезок 
                     if ($w_src==$h_src) 
                     imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, $w_src, $w_src);

$date=time();//вычисляем время в настоящий момент.
            imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory.$date."1.jpg");//сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку,    именем будет текущее время. Сделано, чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых    имен.
//почему    именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается анимирование gif    изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень приятно читать его    комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то движение.
$avatar =    $path_to_90_directory. $date."1.jpg";//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.
$delfull = $path_to_90_directory.$filename; 
            unlink ($delfull);//удаляем оригинал загруженного изображения, он нам    больше не нужен. Задачей было - получить миниатюру.
$result7 =    mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE    login='$old_login'",$db);//извлекаем текущий аватар пользователя

            $myrow7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7);
if ($myrow7['avatar'] == $ava)    {//если он стандартный, то не удаляем его, ведь у    нас одна картинка на всех.
            $ava = 1;
            }
            else {unlink    ($myrow7['avatar']);}//если аватар был свой, то    удаляем его

}
            else 
                    {
                                          //в    случае несоответствия формата, выдаем соответствующее сообщение

                    exit ("Аватар должен быть в    формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>");

                                          }
}
$result4 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET    avatar='$avatar' WHERE login='$old_login'",$db);//обновляем аватар в базе

            if ($result4=='TRUE') {//если верно, то отправляем на личную страничку
            echo "<html><head><meta    http-equiv='Refresh' content='5;    URL=page.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']."'></head><body>Ваша аватарка изменена! Вы    будете перемещены через 5 сек. Если не хотите ждать, то <a href='page.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']."'>нажмите    сюда.</a></body></html>";}
      } 
            ?>
```

Comment: Совет: вычлените из этого хаоса нужный кусок кода, обрамите его, чтобы он подсвечивался, и задайте конкретный вопрос, иначе 100% вам никто не ответит ни на что.

Comment: Вопрос из серии "Где я точку с запятой пропустил"? Может стоит ограничивать объемы кода в вопросах?

Comment: я выписал то место в начале вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$old_login и будет логин юзверя!

```
$new_avatar = $old_login . "1.jpg";

imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory.$new_avatar);//сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку,    именем будет текущее время. Сделано, чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых    имен.
//почему    именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается анимирование gif    изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень приятно читать его    комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то движение.
$avatar =    $path_to_90_directory.$new_avatar;//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.
```

Внимательно нужно смотреть код!

P.S. А теперь поковыряйте свой моск на предмет если логин юзверя будет русским!!!

Comment: ну во первых я так уже делал и результат 0!!!!!! русским логины не делают обычно. Ну ты и моск конешн, еще и меня обсираешь!

Comment: *ROLF*
А еще пользователи всегда вводят e-mail в поле "E-mail"....

Comment: Если логин не хранится в переменной $old_login - значит у Вас какие-то траблы с авторизацией. В любом случае, логин должен быть где-то в сессии. На край - придется извлечь его дополнительным запросом из БД - я так подозреваю, что $_SESSION["id"] - это id пользователя (И не понятно, какой понт в этом случае обновлять строку таблицы проводя поиск по текстовому полю?).

Comment: Запрос из бд тоже выполнял. ВСЕ ДЕЛАЛ ПРАВИЛЬНО. СВЕРИЛ С ОБРАЗЦОМ НА ДРУГОЙ СТРАНИЦЕ. Результат: ава не меняется, предыдущая ава удаляется из папки avatars и предыдущая ава (не знаю каким образом) сохроняется на странице пользователя.

Comment: почему так получается не знаю. Все было прально $_SESSION['login']."1.jpg". если изменить это на $_SESSION['login']."31.jpg" или любое другое число подставить то он 1 раз изменит потом происходит тоже самое. Че делать?)

Comment: Остается только одна классическая ошибка - в ДНК. Код целиком в студию...)